# Label with text copy functionality creation in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I've got the following tkinter classes that give copy/paste functionality to Entries and copy functionality to Labels. However, I'm not sure how to get the CPLabel class to retrieve the text from the text parameter. When I run the program as is, the CPLabel is packed as evidenced by a space where it should appear, however, no text shows.

```
class CPEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<Control-c>', self.copy)
        self.bind('<Control-v>', self.paste)

    def copy(self, event):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        selected_text = self.selection_get()
        self.clipboard_append(selected_text)

    def paste(self, event):
        self.delete(0, END)
        pasted_text = self.clipboard_get()
        self.insert(0, pasted_text)


class CPLabel(CPEntry):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        CPEntry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(state="readonly", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, cursor="arrow", textvariable=None)
        self.insert(0, kwargs.get('text', ''))
```

The text that should be displayed is what is within the text parameter. For example, the CPLabel below should display 'Enter a prime number for the value of p'.

```
pLabel = CPLabel(root, text = 'Enter a prime number for the value of p')
```

If you could let me know what I'm doing wrong, or how to get this to work properly that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can't insert anything into your Entry *after* you've put it in readonly mode!  Switch the order of those last two lines of code.  Also, you really need to strip out the `text` parameter from the **kwargs that you pass to `CPEntry.__init__()` - that's not actually a valid option for an Entry, it's being interpreted as an abbreviated form of `textvariable`, which is NOT something you want to set to a random string.

Comment: Thank you. I should have seen that.